# Android: MediaPlayer- How to avoid music to replay on restarting the App

Tags: android, mobile

I am working on an application where I populated a gridview displaying icons. I need to play music every time the icon is clicked.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    final MediaPlayer fire = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.drawable.fire);
    final MediaPlayer night = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.drawable.night);


    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;
            ////

            if(isPlaying) {
                switch (position)
                {

                    case 0:                           
                            fire.setLooping(true);
                            fire.start();
                            fire.setVolume(0.34f, 0.34f);
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fire2);               

                        break;
                    case 1:

                            night.setLooping(true);
                            night.start();
                            night.setVolume(0.34f, 0.34f);
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.night2);

                        break;


                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I press the back- button and minimize the app, The music keeps playing(which is supposed to happen). But when I open the app again, it restarts and all the icons are set back to its original state and the music from the previous instance of the app keeps playing. When I hit the play music icon again, a new layer of music plays making it really annoying and the app totally useless to use when restarted.

I know I am supposed to save the state and restore it in the onRestart method.
Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a service to use the media player to play a music without the application opened. Check this tutorial: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-ii

Probably what is happening is that when you reopen the application the previous activity is closed and the onCreate method is executed,

Comment: So how do I save the music player state and restore it when the app restarts?

Comment: That is why you should use a service and you should not put the music player in an activity!